# Neural network time series prediction tool

Tags: time-series, prediction, neural-networks

What are some of the state of the art time series prediction tool with neural network?

Comment: Please, add what input(s) will be for the prediction model, and how long time period or sampling point do you consider to be a unit, input size to the model. Also what you want to predict. If you did some research or tried specific model, please share. Popular in natural language processing domain...the Transformer (GPT)? Here is one post, https://medium.com/intel-tech/how-to-apply-transformers-to-time-series-models-spacetimeformer-e452f2825d2e#:~:text=Applying%20multi-head%20attention%20to%20time%20series%20could%20produce,data%20points%20into%20the%20future%2C%20if%20not%20more.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not difficult by starting building simple LSTM models. Based on the simple (and working) structures, add new features / more complicated ingredients to the models and see whether the performance is improved.

For example:
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2022/01/the-complete-lstm-tutorial-with-implementation/

Starting from those codes can give a better sense of why do the models work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please, add contents in "new features/more complicated ingredients". I haven't seen LSTM variance.

Comment: @CloudCho, what do you mean by *LSTM variance*?

Comment: @RichardHardy I was asking what different types of LSTM is out there. I searched it by myself and one of foundings, https://www.exxactcorp.com/blog/Deep-Learning/5-types-of-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-and-what-to-do-with-them. I don't see feature nor ingredient in LSTM in the Internet.

Comment: @CloudCho, OK, but what do you mean by *LSTM variance*? An LSTM model for variance? The variance of LSTM predictions? Something else?

Comment: @RichardHardy Sorry for confusion. It meant something else. It meant different types of LSTM neural network structure. By the way, is there any LSTM model for variance? Also regarding, variance of LSTM output, how do you measure? The variance sounds like subjective.